# Highlight a set of Rows in GridPanel Ext.net (ExtJS)

Tags: javascript, asp.net, extjs, ext.net

Required to highlight set of rows in a Ext.net `gridPannel` color which required to highlight

Current approach is to call the below function on rendering the GridPannel:

```
 function (value, meta, record, rowIndex,columnIndex,store) 
    {

                    color= record.data["ColorValue"];
                    var style = document.createElement('style');
                    style.type = 'text/css';
                    style.innerHTML = '.cssClass'+rowIndex+' {   background color:'+color+'}';
                    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
                    grid.store.getAt(rowIndex).set("mySelected", "cssClass"+rowIndex);
    }
```

But with this approach: it **highlights all the rows with the same color** .. a test `alert(color);` fetched the correct different color of each color from the GridPannel

Any Good approach for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override getRowClass method in GridView.

```
new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    [...],
    viewConfig: {
        getRowClass: function(record, index, rowParams, store) { return 'some-class'; }
    }
});
```

Or if you need apply colors post-render, you can try setting for each row:

```
grid.getView().getRow(0).className += 'some-class';
```

Note: this examples are based on ExtJS 3.4 API, but i bet there is something similiar in 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

With ExtJS 4 you can use the [highlight](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dom.Element-method-highlight) method of the [row element](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.view.Table-method-getNode) of the records in the grid store.

```
var store = grid.getStore();
var view  = grid.getView();
var node;

store.each(function(record) {
    if (record.get('fieldname') !== 'your_condition') return;

    //Return the node given the passed Record, or index or node.
    node = view.getNode(record);
    if (!node) return;

    Ext.get(node).highlight();
});
```